# export map itinerary to use it for a device like (TomTom)

Tags: gpx

I have a map/direction based application using Google Maps API v3. So far I have been able to display the map and show directions between 2 locations.

**Question**

Can I export the direction display from this map to a device like tomtom, to show the itinerary on it?
any advices , what should i search for ?

Comment: Your question is too broad and off-topic. What have you tried? Did you search for that before asking? You need to show some efforts. Nobody is here to code for you, and this site should not be used to ask people to point you to an external library, tutorial, etc.

Comment: i want advices , like what i should search ? , and is this possible to do it on my map....  i'm not searching for somebody to code for me

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But here is a place to ask question when you have a clear coding problem. No questions like "how should I do that" or "can you point me to...", etc. As a tip, I would search for "Google Maps API v3 directions to GPX" or something like that...

Comment: @MrUpsidown ok sir thank you , this is what i want , like this information ( ... As a tip, I would search for "Google Maps API v3 directions to GPX" or something like that...)